# Find smallest solution in Solve's solution set

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

When an equation has multiple solutions, how do you find the first solution?

Example:

Say we're trying to find the first positive x-intercept of the cosine function:

$cos(x)=0 \land x \ge 0$

[image]

Running `Solve`, we obtain the set of solutions:

```
solutions = Solve[Cos[x] == 0 && x >= 0, x]
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{1}{2} \left(4 \pi  c_1-\pi
>    \right),c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\land c_1\geq 1\right]\right\},\left\{x\to
>    \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{1}{2} \left(4 \pi  c_1+\pi \right),c_1\in
>    \mathbb{Z}\land c_1\geq 0\right]\right\}\right\}$

To proceed, we need to find the `C[1]` that minimizes the substitution for `x`. How do we do this?

Comment: You could just provide explicit brackets, guessing the upper limit after looking at a plot: `Solve[{Cos[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 2}, x]`

Comment: A numeric approach: ``Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]; NLimit[
 ArgMin[{eps*x^2 + Cos[x]^2, x > 0}, x], eps -> 0]``.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Minimize` + `MinimalBy` work on the test case:

```
MinimalBy[Minimize[x /. #, C[1]] & /@ solutions, First]
(*  {{π/2, {C[1] -> 0}}}  *)
```

Comment: I didn't realize `ConditionalExpression` works inside `Minimize` and friends. I should've known! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like

```
MinimalSolveSolution[expr_, x_, o___] :=
  MinimalSolveSolution[Solve[expr, x, o]]

MinimalSolveSolution[sol:{{x_ -> _}..}] :=
  iMinimalSolveSolution[x /. sol]

MinimalSolveSolution[__] = $Failed;

iMinimalSolveSolution[l_List] := Min[iMinimalSolveSolution /@ l]

iMinimalSolveSolution[ConditionalExpression[val_, cond_]] := 
  MinValue[{val, cond}, Union[Cases[val, _C, {0, ∞}]]]

iMinimalSolveSolution[v_] := v
```

I didn't really stress test this solution, but it works for your given input:

```
MinimalSolveSolution[Cos[x] == 0 && x >= 0, x]
```

> ```
> π/2
> ```